# Есть ли готовый скрипт фиксированного блока в углу сайта, раскрывающегося в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Если ли готовый скрипт фиксированного окна в углу сайта с popup окном?

Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на плей открывается popup окно и воспроизводится видео из ютуба.

[Вот сайт](http://www.transitplus.ru/), на котором увидел  (только оно у них появляется под конец страницы)

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var video = document.querySelector('iframe'),
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset, // размер прокрутки от верха страницы
    bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight, // высота контента всего документа
    subtr = bodyHeight - scrollTop;
  if (subtr < 1200) {
    video.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
}

iframe {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <iframe width="300" height="215" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6x3IVzWeVDw" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```